# self hosted page2rss alternative

Tags: linux, rss

While page2rss been reliable so far, I'd like to move as many things I rely on to my own servers.

Core functionality:
Point it at a web page. Generates RSS feed I can read with an rss feed reader. One feed per page.

Since this is for webcomics, I should ideally get the whole webpage content, or selected elements inline in the feed. (If in doubt, page2rss meets my basics in terms of what it outputs).

Platform:
Linux/ubuntu 14.04 if it needs a web server. I'm not picky over UI here - for *basic* use I'm fine with text mode configuration file and no webui, and/or it being something that I run via crontab.

I'm fine with software written in almost any language, but sane install notes are a must. I currently run applications on php, and I have mysql and postgres instances, so if I need a database for the application either would do

Nice to have:
A webpage where I can click or drag on to select elements for the rss feed or some other way to select what elements are included.

Licence/cost
I prefer free/gratis software. I'd consider paid software if its *exceptional*. Its for personal use so I'm not too picky over licences, and if its open source, I'm cool with that.

Comment: got any luck with this search? I'm looking for the same